trying to use a long(ish) container template file
Just getting to grips with podman (don't have docker experience, either).
I have been trying to figure out why a container file was failing, eventually I found it has nothing to do with my content, but with the length of the file.
The command I used was :
podman build -f ./UbuntuTest.containerfile -t testmyubuntu1

The test container file is:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN echo "Line 1"
RUN echo "Line 2"
RUN echo "Line 3"
RUN echo "Line 4"
RUN echo "Line 5"
RUN echo "Line 6"
RUN echo "Line 7"
RUN echo "Line 8"
RUN echo "Line 9"
RUN echo "Line 10"
RUN echo "Line 11"
RUN echo "Line 12"
RUN echo "Line 13"
RUN echo "Line 14"
RUN echo "Line 15"
RUN echo "Line 16"
RUN echo "Line 17"
RUN echo "Line 18"
RUN echo "Line 19"
RUN echo "Line 20"
RUN echo "Line 21"
RUN echo "Line 22"
RUN echo "Line 23"
RUN echo "Line 24"
RUN echo "Line 25"
RUN echo "Line 26"
RUN echo "Line 27"
RUN echo "Line 28"
RUN echo "Line 29"
RUN echo "Line 30"
RUN echo "Line 31"
RUN echo "Line 32"
RUN echo "Line 33"
RUN echo "Line 34"
RUN echo "Line 35"
RUN echo "Line 36"
RUN echo "Line 37"
RUN echo "Line 38"
RUN echo "Line 39"
RUN echo "Line 40"
RUN echo "Line 41"
RUN echo "Line 42"
RUN echo "Line 43"
RUN echo "Line 44"
RUN echo "Line 45"
RUN echo "Line 46"
RUN echo "Line 47"
RUN echo "Line 48"
RUN echo "Line 49"
RUN echo "Line 50"
RUN echo "Line 51"
RUN echo "Line 52"
RUN echo "Line 53"
RUN echo "Line 54"
RUN echo "Line 55"
RUN echo "Line 56"
RUN echo "Line 57"
RUN echo "Line 58"
RUN echo "Line 59"
RUN echo "Line 60"
RUN echo "Line 61"
RUN echo "Line 62"
RUN echo "Line 63"
RUN echo "Line 64"
RUN echo "Line 65"
RUN echo "Line 66"
RUN echo "Line 67"
RUN echo "Line 68"
RUN echo "Line 69"
RUN echo "Line 70"
RUN echo "Line 71"
RUN echo "Line 72"
RUN echo "Line 73"
RUN echo "Line 74"
RUN echo "Line 75"
RUN echo "Line 76"
RUN echo "Line 77"
RUN echo "Line 78"
RUN echo "Line 79"
RUN echo "Line 80"
RUN echo "Line 81"
RUN echo "Line 82"
RUN echo "Line 83"
RUN echo "Line 84"
RUN echo "Line 85"
RUN echo "Line 86"
RUN echo "Line 87"
RUN echo "Line 88"
RUN echo "Line 89"
RUN echo "Line 90"
RUN echo "Line 91"
RUN echo "Line 92"
RUN echo "Line 93"
RUN echo "Line 94"
RUN echo "Line 95"
RUN echo "Line 96"
RUN echo "Line 97"
RUN echo "Line 98"
RUN echo "Line 99"
RUN echo "Line 100"

CMD ["/bin/bash"]

It seems to die around line 46...

ERRO[0009] error unmounting /home/user/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/499af90d3b3568f341a7a05014de08060d778e8df4c2c06e2bbedad088e2719b/merged: invalid argument
ERRO[0010] error deleting build container "43d7eb900fa3f266f35588b9bfb620cc05abfa13e5cc4cb3c9b0373ca21b291e": identifier is not a container
Error: identifier is not a container: error preparing container for next step: error mounting new container: error mounting build container "2a2cd2c8...

I am just trying to append a reasonable chunk of text to a file. I have seen the copy and add commands, but I want to append to a file, not copy a new file. I was not aware of any restriction on lengths of the file, it maybe seems to be creating an intermediate container for every line? A side question, if this is so, do I need to tidy these up?

Your command succeeded when I tried it with podman 5.0.0 on Fedora CoreOS (Next stream 40.20240331.1.0). Which Podman version are you running?

fine on debian, podman 4.3, btrfs filesystem - could you be hitting a problem with numbers of layers of overlays or something?

I am running 3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1.22.04.2 which I am guessing is the latest default version for Ubuntu 22.04. I will have a look at how to upgrade independently of the OS.

In terms of number of layers of overlays, so each command creates a new layer/overlay I am guessing? Is there a maximum number of layers/overlays? I am guessing you wouldn't want too many. I was planning to append a few hundred lines to a couple of different files. If each command is a new overlay, I would have hundreds of overlays... probably bad? I guess as an alternative, I can get the source of the original files, append my text to them, and copy/replace them back, and then be able to do that in a couple of commands and hence only have a couple of overlays instead of hundreds.
